# Code that allows a keyboard to navigate internal page links with OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, accessibility

I have the following code on my Mac:

```
<a href="#content">Skip navigation</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content">Lots of code here, with more links.</div>
```

In OSX Chrome and Safari, I can tab to the top link, press enter, and the screen scrolls down to the `<div id="content">`. However, when I press the tab button again, it turns out the first link is still active, and I end up tabbing through the navigation.

In Windows, this code works as expected (i.e. I use the link to successfully avoid having to tab through the navigation at the top of the page).

Can anyone tell me what code I need to make the page's internal links properly navigable with a keyboard on OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is the answer, after a flash of inspiration.

You need to have an href="#" on the target <a id="content">. This will make it correctly navigable-to using a Mac's keyboard.

```
<a href="#content">Skip navigation</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1.html">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
<a id="content" href="#"></a>
<div>Lots of code here, with more links.</div>
```

Obviously, this is not ideal, as it introduces extra mark-up, but it is the only way I could find to get it working.

Comment: or change `<div>` to `<div id="content" tabindex="-1">`